# Endpoint design for a data retrieval orientated ASP.NET webapi

Tags: asp.net, api

I am designing a system that uses **asp.net webapi** to serve data that is used by a number of jquery grid controls.  The grids call back for the data after the page has loaded.  I have a User table and a Project table.  In between these is a Membership table that stores the many to many relationships.

```
User
userID
Username
Email

Project
projectID
name
code

Membership
membershipID
projectID
userID
```

My question is what is best way to describe this data and relationships as a webapi?

I have the following routes

```
GET: user  // gets all users
GET: user/{id}  // gets a single user
GET: project
GET: project/{id}
```

I think one way to do it would be to have:

```
GET: user/{id}/projects  // gets all the projects for a given user
GET: project/{id}/users  // gets all the users for a given project
```

I'm not sure what the configuration of the routes and the controllers should look like for this, or even if this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Modern standard for that is a very simple approach called [REST](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) Just read carefully and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ph0en1x said, REST is the new trend for web services. It looks like you're on the right track already with some of your proposed routes. I've been doing some REST design at my job and here are some things to think about:

1. Be consistent with your routes. You're already doing that, but watch out for when/if another developer starts writing routes. A user wants consistent routes for using your API.
2. Keep it simple. A major goal should be discoverability. What I mean is that if I'm a regular user of your system, and I know there are users and projects and maybe another entity called "goal" ... I want to guess at /goal and get a list of goals. That makes a user *very* happy. The less they have to reference the documentation, the better.
3. Avoid appending a ton of junk to the query string. We suffer from this currently at my job. Once the API gets some traction, users might want more fine grained control. Be careful not to turn the URL into something messy. Something like /user?sort=asc&limit=5&filter=...&projectid=...
4. Keep the URL nice and simple. Again I love this in a well design API. I can easily remember something like http://api.twitter.com. Something like http://www.mylongdomainnamethatishardtospell.com/api/v1/api/user_entity/user ... is much harder to remember and is frustrating.
5. Just because a REST API is on the web doesn't mean it's all that different than a normal method in client side only code. I've read arguments that any method should have no more than 3 parameters. This idea is similar to (3). If you find yourself wanting to expand, consider adding more methods/routes, not more parameters.

I know what I want in a REST API these days and that is intuition, discoverability, simplicity and to avoid having to constantly dig through complex documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe my question wasn't clear. I was trying to find out how the more complex routes would be implemented using WebApi controllers as well as the design of the routes themselves.

Comment: I must have been insane when I answered. Ha. It didn't address your question at all. =( I don't know about designing the controllers, but I like your routes for getting projects related to users and users related to projects. Seems fine to me.